# MySQL: having rounded sum not equal to integer

Tags: mysql

I have a query in which I compare a rounded sum to an integer, and I'm receiving unexpected results.

```
SELECT assignments.*
  FROM assignments
  INNER JOIN time_entries
    ON time_entries.assignment_id = assignments.id
  WHERE assignments.organization_id = 2
  AND assignments.allocation_mode = 'fixed'
  AND (fixed_hours is not null)
  HAVING round(sum(time_entries.scheduled_hours)) != round(assignments.fixed_hours);
```

It returns an assignment with `fixed_hours` of `20`. The column is a float.

When I select the sum of the time_entries for that match that record, I get `20.000000298023224`. When I call `round` on that, I get `20`:

```
SELECT
  round(sum(scheduled_hours))
  FROM time_entries
  WHERE assignment_id=112869;
```

And `SELECT round(fixed_hours) from assignments where id=112869` also gives `20`.

And of course `select round(20.000000298023224) = round(20);` returns `1`.

So what's wrong with my query that that record is being returned?

Comment: `round(assignments.fixed_hours)` is getting this value from a randomly selected row in the table. It's very unlikely that it will pick a row that matches the sum of the entire table.

Comment: The big issue is the `SUM` aggregate... with no group by, that's going to collapse all of the individual rows into a single row. MySQL has an extension that allows the query to be processed, while a query like this would throw an error in other RDBMS. One quick fix (not necessarily the most correct fix) would be to add `GROUP BY foo` where foo is the primary key column(s) of the `assignments` table, or barring that, some set of expressions that is unique in the `assignments` table i.e. no two rows will share the same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice try at query summarization :), but you need a group by...

```
SELECT
      assignments.*
FROM assignments
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
            assignment_id
          , ROUND(SUM(time_entries.scheduled_hours)) sum_hrs
      FROM time_entries
      GROUP BY
            assignment_id
) te ON assignments.id = te.assignment_id
WHERE assignments.organization_id = 2
AND assignments.allocation_mode = 'fixed'
AND (fixed_hours IS NOT NULL)
AND te.sum_hrs <> ROUND(assignments.fixed_hours)
;
```